# What things should be done in order to submit the app (or new update) to Appstore after Apple make Xcode 5 compulsory one?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

I am developing IOS app for more than a year now. I have got apps in appstore which was built with xcode 4.6 and ios 6.1. They were doing well untill today when I need to submit an update to one of my app. While submitting the app,
I received:

> This bundle is invalid . New app and app updates submitted to the app store must be build with xcode 5 and ios 7 sdk

After some research I found out that app make this compulsory to use xcode 5 for submission. My question is how should I properly upgrade the machine so that my keychain will remain intact(so are my certificates), I can still build apps for IOS 6 and work with my projects which were built using xcode 4.6.

My main concerns is certificates, I heard that xcode 5.0 needs Mountain Lion 10.8, if I will upgrade the os, keychain will be removed, how will recover the certificate signing requests, private key which identifies the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade only xCode 5 and set deployment target as ios 6.0 or 5.0 and develop app for compatible for iOS 7.

Apple, Inc. recently announced changes to its iOS application developer guidelines, requiring all mobile app submissions from iPad and iPhone app developers to be optimised for the iOS 7 operating system. All apps submitted to the iTunes App Store for review on or after February 1, 2014 must comply with the new guidelines, or they will be automatically rejected and denied distribution through Apple’s app marketplace.

[source](http://www.prweb.com/releases/2014/01/prweb11481049.htm)

Comment: However when I try to install xcode 5, it says need to have Mountain Lion 10.8.4 to install xcode 5.0

Comment: what is your os version

Comment: okay got it. however if I will install OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.4 and 10.8.5) / OS X Mavericks (10.9), will i not loose my keychain datas resulting issue in signing the app while submitting to appstore?

Comment: you backup in iColud keychain

Comment: I thought the same however it does not show keychain in the list to be backed up.

Comment: okay now I decide to go like this, I will export the private associated with the distribution certificate and save this to a location. Upgrade the osx to either 10.8.4(Mountain Lion) or Maverick. Then import the private key to key section of keychain. Download all certificates and provisioning profile after installing xcode 5.0. is this correct? if yes, will it be difficult to import projects to xcode 5.0 which were built with xcode 4.6? if not what else should I do?